# Saving image from array to local library

Tags: iphone, ipad

Issue with saving the image from array to the local library.

The below code is saving the image to the local library but the back ground is in black color.

```
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(drawImage.frame.size);
    [drawImage.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *saveImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[UndoList objectAtIndex:0]];
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(saveImage, nil, nil, nil);
```

When i am using `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()`

```
 saveImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
```

Its saving the last index in array
@All Any one give me an idea of fixing the issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: And the background colour should be what? White? Orange? What have you tried to solve this yourself? Have you read the documentation regarding the functions you are using and checked you are using them correctly? Debugged through your code to check values are set as they should be?

Answer (score 0):

is not black backround but it's with alpha 0 background... because you save PNG image... and why you render layer if you can save drawImage.image ?
save data image in array with **UIImageJPEGRepresentation** no **UIImagePNGRepresentation**